# Pending migrations error when running rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I getting this weird error from Rails:

```
$ rake db:migrate
You have 1 pending migrations:
  20150226203752 CreatePlan
Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.
```

But that's exactly what I'm trying to do!

Anyone knows why I'm getting this?

Answer (score 0):

Things seem to have gone wrong somewhere, run all your migrations again using `rake db:migrate:reset`